# Adding Event Llistener for getOrgChart Anchor Tag

Tags: addeventlistener, getorgchart

This question is specifically for `getOrgChart.js`. 
I am trying to add Onclick function for the Anchor tag in `getOrgChart` like below but getting issues

```
document.getElementsByClassName("get-prev-page").addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

I try to change `anchor tag` in `OrgChart` JS file it self at `INNERHTML` value ..

```
<a title="previous page" class="get-prev-page" href="#" onclick="myFunction()">
```

but again it generates

```
<a title="previous page" class="get-prev-page" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks.